# Is there a specific word to describe the opposite of egotistical - acting for the specific benefit of someone else?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

I am trying to discover a word that means seeing things from another persons perspective or acting for the benefit of a specific person or group of persons, but distinct from altruistic.

Comment: Did a thesaurus suggest anything? altrusitic, charitable, empathetic?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this will fill the need;

al·tru·is·tic

/ˌaltro͞oˈistik/

adjective: altruistic

showing a disinterested and selfless concern for the well-being of others; unselfish.
"it was an entirely altruistic act"

synonyms: unselfish, selfless, compassionate, kind, public-spirited; More
charitable, benevolent, beneficent, philanthropic, humanitarian;

"the desire is to appear purely altruistic with no apparent expectation

Comment: I voted your answer up because it fits the bill but look at the OP's request, specifically last part.

Comment: thanks, I tried to delete it on review, but it simply wouldn't have it.  If you could share a simple way to delete an answer completely I'd deeply appreciate it...

Comment: If it doesn't bother you, don't delete it.  It will be helpful for new users that are directed to this question.

Comment: But if you want to, you can visit your profile, go under questions you've answered and then visit the question and delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

> **empathetic** (adj):
>
> showing an ability to understand and share the feelings of another